# centeredSlide has no effect when using Swiper Element

Tags: swiper.js

I am using the Swiper Elements Web Component in Angular. I have set `centeredslides="true"` but it is not working:

- active slide is the left most visible slide
- there is no way to make the right most slides active

How do I get it to work?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lewx69?file=src%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.html